# Can't update data to database with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble updating the data in the database with codeigniter. This is my controller :

```
  public function update_mission_vision($id)
    {
        $this->securePage();


        $data['mission'] = $mission = $this->about_model->get_mission_vision($id);

        if ($mission == false) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'The mission does not exist.');
            redirect('about/manage-miteri-mission-vision');     
        } else {
            if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required|max_length[240]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('details', 'details', 'required|max_length[240]');

                if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                    $added_on = time();

                    $this->about_model->update_mission_vision($added_on, $id);

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'mission updated successfully.');
                    redirect('about/manage-miteri-mission-vision');
                }

            }
        }

        $data['title'] = "$mission->title | miteripkr.com";
        $data['keywords'] = "$mission->title";
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('about-us/update_mission_vision', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('miteri', $data);
    }
```

And this is my models :

```
function get_all_mission_vision($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        if ($limit)
        {
            $this->db->limit($limit. $offset);

        }
        return $this->db->get('mission_vision');

    }


function get_mission_vision($id)
{
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('mission_vision');

        if ($query->num_rows()) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}



function update_mission_vision($id, $added_on)
{
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->set('title', $this->input->post('title'));
        $this->db->set('details', $this->input->post('details')); 
        $this->db->set('added_on', $added_on);
        $this->db->update('mission_vision');
}
```

This is my view :

```
<**div class="container-fluid" style="background:#fff; margin-top:10px; border-radius:5px; min-height:600px; margin-bottom:10px;">

    <form action="" method="post" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>

        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">update mission & vision</a></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"> Title for Post</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title" value="<?php echo set_value('title', $mission->title)?>"> 
            <?php echo form_error('title');?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"> Details for Post</label>
            <textarea class="ckeditor" name="details" placeholder="Enter Details" style="height:200px;"><?php echo set_value('details', $mission->details); ?></textarea>
            <?php echo form_error('details');?>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" value="update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> update</span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

It even prints a success message but my data is not updated, why?

Comment: it's not clear how your are passing posted data to your model. you should pass data to `update_mission_vision($id, $added_on,$post_data)` and use that data in model instead of `input->post`.

Comment: can you write models for me if u dont mind im just a beginner so it would be great if u help me with models code .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the call of the function `update_mission_vision`. You switched `$id` and `$added_on`.
And of course, like @Kamran Adil said, you have to give the post data to your model.

Update:
Here is an example how i write my update function in a model. So you can have look and make your own update function.

```
/**
 * @name string TABLE_NAME Holds the name of the table in use by this model
 */
const TABLE_NAME = 'table';

/**
 * @name string PRI_INDEX Holds the name of the tables' primary index used in this model
 */
const PRI_INDEX = 'field';

/**
 * Updates selected record in the database
 *
 * @param Array $data Associative array field_name=>value to be updated
 * @param Array $where Optional. Associative array field_name=>value, for where condition. If specified, $id is not used
 * @return int Number of affected rows by the update query
 */
public function update(Array $data, $where = array()) {
        if (!is_array($where)) {
            $where = array(self::PRI_INDEX => $where);
        }
    $this->db->update(self::TABLE_NAME, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you lost the $id in your URL.

Put a hidden input in your view with the $id, then in the controller, asign this `$id = $this->input->post('id');` to get the $id. And the delete $id in your controller `update_mission_vision() {`